# How to switch n columns to rows of a r rows pandas dataframe (n*r rows in the final dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's take this dataframe :

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(Col1=["a","c"],Col2=["b","d"],Col3=[1,3],Col4=[2,4]))
  Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
0    a    b     1     2
1    c    d     3     4
```

I would like to have one row per value in column Col1 and column Col2 (n=2 and r=2 so the expected dataframe have 2*2 = 4 rows).

Expected result :

```
    Ind Value  Col3  Col4
0  Col1     a     1     2
1  Col1     c     3     4
2  Col2     b     1     2
3  Col2     d     3     4
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas melt does the job here; the rest just has to do with repositioning and renaming the columns appropriately. 
Use [pandas melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to transform the dataframe, using Col3 and 4 as the index variables. melt typically converts from wide to long.
Next step - reindex the columns, with variable and value as lead columns.
Finally, rename the columns appropriately.

```
 (df.melt(id_vars=['Col3','Col4']) 
  .reindex(['variable','value','Col3','Col4'],axis=1)
  .rename({'variable':'Ind','value':'Value'},axis=1)
  )

    Ind Value   Col3   Col4
0   Col1    a   1      2
1   Col1    c   3      4
2   Col2    b   1      2
3   Col2    d   3      4
```

Comment: Add some description to answer, because it is only code answer..